# Do you need a return type method to be handled in front end?

Tags: java

So I am trying to get more insight on Java methods as I am still new to all this. And in my method type I declared as below:

```
public int insert_url(long nodeid,String url,String startdt,String enddt,int enable) {
    try {
        //   UrlLink attr = em.find(UrlLink.class,n);

        String sql="INSERT INTO urllink(NODEID,URL,STARTDT,ENDDT,ENABLE) VALUES("+nodeid+",'"+url+"','"+startdt+"','"+enddt+"',"+enable+")";

        em.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();

        return 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return -1;
    }
}
```

And in my front end, I called it simply like below:

```
try {
    fileFacade.insert_url(nd.getNodeid(), "f0=" + nd.getNodeid() + "&ts=" + hash, currentDate, defaultDate, 1);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // error should be handled
}
```

Initially, I was using `void` method rather than `int`. My question is if I am not using a return method,can it be handled in the front end?

In the even that the end user encounters any error, they ought to know an error occurred.

Comment: "In the even that the end user encounters any error, they ought to know an error occurred." - That's why exceptions are generally preferred over return codes. I would strongly recommend removing the try/catch from your method. Let the exception propagate. I'd also recommend following Java naming conventions (`insertUrl` instead of `insert_url`) and *definitely* start using parameterized SQL instead of putting values directly into your SQL - you've currently got a big SQL Injection Attack vulnerability.

Comment: I see. So allow the try catch in the front end?

Comment: Potentially. Or configure whatever's hosting the frontend with a generic "what to do on error" policy, rather than having a try/catch block in every frontend method.